# 2 definitions of vector fields on $\mathbb R^n$: maps $\mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and smooth sections of $T\mathbb R^n$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, tangent-bundle

One definition says a vector field is a map $f:\mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$.

Another definition says a vector field is a smooth section of $T\mathbb R^n$, the tangent bundle of $\mathbb R^n$.

The intuition for a vector field on $\mathbb R^n$ is that it is a function that attaches a vector to each point in $\mathbb R^n$.

Are these 2 definitions equivalent? Do they agree with intuition?

Comment: In case of $\Bbb R^n$ they are equivalent because the tangent space at any point in $\Bbb R^n$ is just $\Bbb R^n$ itself. A smooth section of $\Bbb R^n$ is then just a smooth function from $\Bbb R^n$ to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two definitions you posted aren't equivalent, since the second one has a smoothness criterion, but the first one doesn't. If you were to delete the smoothness criterion though, they would be the same. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be covered by a single chart, $T\mathbb{R}^n \simeq \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$. You can then show that a section on $T\mathbb{R}^n$ will define a unique function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! Does this equivalence of definitions also apply to vector fields on general manifolds $M$? That is, can a vector field on $M$ be defined both as a map $M \longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and as a section of $TM$?

Comment: No.  The section definition is the right one on smooth manifolds in general.